# Extract string from URL using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, url

My code could be given any of the 3 possible URLS below, and I'd like to extract the user name  '**mrsmith**' which could be any kind of user name depending on the URL being passed, while the 'somewebsite', '/artist/' and '/portfolio/' remain constant:

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/artist/mrsmith
http://mrsmith.somewebsite.com/
http://mrsmith.somewebsite.com/portfolio/variablenames
```

Is there an elegant way to do this using regex?

Comment: Do you want to *extract* it if it exists, or do you want to *remove* it? Which bit are you going to use - the `mrsmith`, or the rest of the URL?

Comment: I was just looking to grab the user name mrsmith, I will edit the original post to be clearer.

Comment: If you are looking to extract the subdomain (which just happens to be a name, but that in itself is irrelevant) then that is what you need to say.

Comment: @ChrisL as slugster said, it's so hard to differentiate between the user name and the subdomain names.

Comment: I guess, what I was wondering - is it possible to have something that says, "if it's NOT "www.", then it's the user name, otherwise, look for the username at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below regex would look for mrsmith just after a `/` symbol followed by a `.` or `$`(end)

```
(?<=\/)mrsmith(?=\.|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zZ8vG3/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\/)` A positive lookbehind is used. It sets the marker just after to the `/` symbol.
- `mrsmith(?=\.|$)` again it checks for the string `mrsmith`, if it's there then again check whether the symbol which follows the `mrsmith` string is a dot or end. If these conditions are true, then it matches the corresponding `mrsmith` string.

**Update:**

Your regex would be,

```
(?=www\.).*\/\K.*|(?<=http:\/\/)[^\.]*
```

OR

```
(?=www\.).*\/\K.*|(?!www\.)(?<=http:\/\/)[^\.]*
```

It matches the string after last `/` when a line contains `www.` or it matches the sting after `http://` upto the first `.` if `www.` is not present on that line.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zZ8vG3/2)

Comment: I thought this was working until I realize that 'mrsmith' was 'hardcoded' into this regex.  I was hoping where the user name 'mrsmith' could be any username chosen.

Comment: Thanks again, I looked it up and \K isn't part of regex for C# unfortunately, but thanks for all the help!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

simplest regex would be

```
http:\/\/(.*?)\..*\/(.*)
```

this will match both groups the subdomain and the end path

so these will be the match for three lines above

`MATCH 1`

1. [7-10]  `www`
2. [34-41] `mrsmith`

`MATCH 2`

1. [49-56] `mrsmith`
2. [73-73] ``

`MATCH 3`

1. [81-88] `mrsmith`
2. [115-128]   `variablenames`

now you may choose which group is the username

for example if first group has `www` then definitely second is the name other wise the first

try it here http://regex101.com/r/kE9bB4/1